# Angularjs/Bootstrap Modal on Facebook App

Tags: angularjs, facebook, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Facebook App made with Angularjs but I have a problem with modals.
On browser when I open the model even with page scroll down the modal appear on screen, but on facebook always apear on the top of the page so I need to scroll up to see the modal.
I made an simple modal like angularjs/Bootstrap documentation shows...
Anyone had this problem?

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          template: 'simple apptext',

          resolve: {
            items: function () {
              return $scope.items;
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: Well unless you're trying to inject items into the modal you can take the whole resolve part out.  But I'm guessing it's a CSS error.  Have you checked the browsers console to see if there were any errors, or watched the network inspector on your browser's developer tools to see if the CSS files are being loaded?  You could always add custom CSS to the modal by specifiying `windowClass: 'modalClass'` and then making a CSS class called 'modalClass'

Comment: I can do that, but what property should I override? I want that my app work on facebook and at the browser.

Comment: Anyone had this problem too?